# Word or phrase which indicates some shared knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun which is kind of word or phrase that is used to indicate the existence of some unspoken knowledge that the speaker has.

For example:

> Her use of the the word "pincushion" was a deliberate ___________ intended to let him know that she knew his secret identity, without alerting those she suspected to be listening in.

I've a feeling this word begins with an S and has 3 or 4 syllables, but am drawing a long blank in my memory...

Comment: I can actually live with this sentence: *Her use of the the word "pincushion" was intended to let him know that she knew his secret identity, without alerting those she suspected to be listening in.*

Oh.. and the word you are looking for is *Surreptitious*.

Comment: The word I am looking for is a noun, I've clarified my phrasing of the question a bit.

Comment: It doesn't mean what you are looking for, but the word that would fit that sentence would be codeword -> "Pincushion was a codeword..." However among antonyms of secrets, you have "*revelation*" and "*disclosure*" but no word beginning with an S I'm afraid.

Comment: Keep em coming :) This word isn't necessarily related to spying or secrecy, could be (for example) to tell that someone had been to the same university as you without being so much of a bore as to say it out loud, or similar.

Comment: Well, *clue* can work here, but may be too generic.

Comment: Were you thinking of *shibboleth*? It starts with 's' and has 3 syllables, as required, but normally functions in a somewhat different sense of 'identifying someone'.

Comment: @Lawrence Ah hah! Indeed that is the word that's been foxing me for several days. I see I had the meaning slightly off, which accounts for my not being able to find it myself!  Make an answer out of it and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MatthewGilliard Ok, done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Shibboleth* comes close, though it's not used in the way you intend. [Historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth), it was used as a proxy test related to whether the person started the word with the *sh-* sound or the *s-* sound.

> **Shibboleth** *noun*
> A custom, principle, or belief distinguishing a particular class or group of people, especially a long-standing one regarded as outmoded or no longer important: *liberal shibboleths about education*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shibboleth?q=Shibboleth)
>
> A shibboleth ... in its original signification and in a meaning it still bears today, is a word or custom whose variations in pronunciation or style can be used to differentiate members of ingroups from those of outgroups. Within the mindset of the ingroup, a connotation or value judgment of correct/incorrect or superior/inferior can be ascribed to the two variants.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth)

Comment: Thank you. This is the word I was looking for, in the sense:
"a word or custom whose variations in pronunciation or style can be used to differentiate members of ingroups from those of outgroups" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth

Comment: @MatthewGilliard Thanks. I prefer that historical usage - it's now added to the answer. :)

Comment: no one will understand this if you say it, some of these other suggestions seem a better fit to my ears

Comment: @Matt I've clarified the usage of this term in the first paragraph.

Comment: Oh wow! Absolute genius!!! However, if you are writing a book, a generic reader may have to dive in the dictionary. Eloquence is a turn on. Just saying :)

Answer (score 6):

You might be looking for ***cipher***, "a coded message" (sense 7, [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cypher?s=t)). It begins with an /s/ sound and works in your context:

> Her use of the word "pincushion" was a deliberate cipher intended to
>   let him know that she knew his secret identity.

***Intimation***, meaning "the action of making something known, *especially in an indirect way*" ([here](https://www.google.com/#q=define+intimation)), also works in your context.

Other suggestions:

- wink
- signal
- nod
- cue
- clue
- hint

***Wink*** works especially well, since winks are usually done on the sly, under the radar of others who are around:

> Her use of the word "pincushion" was a deliberate wink intended to let him know that she knew his secret identity.

Comment: Yes, you've got the gist of my poorly-phrased question, which is reassuring. We've not hit the exact one yet, though I do like the metaphorical use of "wink".

Comment: I think "signal" is the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

**"subtleness"** (or **"subtlety"**) seems to be the word you're looking for.

"Her use of the the word "pincushion" was a deliberate **subtleness/subtlety** intended to let him know that she knew his secret identity, without alerting those she suspected to be listening in."

> - [**subtleness**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/subtleness) - the property of being subtle, of avoiding brute force and instead being clever or skillful.
>
> "The movie was praised for the subtleness of its themes. None of it came off as being too preachy."

"subtlety" is a good fit too.

Comment: The phrase "was a deliberate subtleness" sounds a bit unnatural to me. Does it sound perfectly fine to you?

Comment: @Silenus  "subtlety" sounds more natural.

Comment: Just another datapoint FYI the phrase "a deliberate subtleness" sounds fine to me (GB-en).

Answer (score 1):

I think [**tell**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell) works best here

> to give information to (someone) by speaking or writing

*Merriam-Webster*

Answer (score 1):

If there is an agreement between the speaker and listener (or group) beforehand, you might call such a word a **dog-whistle**, implying something that you know the speaker will hear a certain way that others will not. This term is often used in politics, for example, where one might, say, accuse a right-wing politician of using a term like "limiting Israeli expansion" as a dog-whistle to his anti-semitic supporters.